# finding similarity of a new datapoint

Tags: data-science-model, recommender-system, cosine-distance

I have built a recommendation engine using cosine similarity. When I want to find all the records similar to a given record that is already present in the dataset it works. Consider a case, a user enters a new record which does not exist in the similarity matrix, to find and recommend similar records I am adding the new data point into the dataset built the similarity matrix and then pick the similar records, Is there a better way to handle this problem?

Adding more details

```
data=["document1", "document2", "document", ... "documentN"]
count_matrix = count.fit_transform(data)
cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(count_matrix, count_matrix)
```

Comment: How do you represent each of your data points?

Comment: Why do you rebuild your matrix again? Instead you can simply calculate the new sample's cos distance to existent samples and append the result to the matrix.

Comment: @FatemehAsgarinejad I have added the code please check

Comment: @Shahriyar Mammadli how do I do that? in the above code if there is a new document N+1, should I add the new document to data2 and get count_matrix2 and then compute cosine_sim2 and append it to cosine_sim? The problem is data2 will have only the new record then how do I calculate the distance for other records?

Comment: Store your previous data, use either sql database or any other format

Comment: @ShahriyarMammadli ok I can save cosine_sim somehow, what will be the new input?
it should contain all the previous data right that is data=["document1", "document2", "document", ... "documentN"] + "newDocument" right?

Comment: No, have two separate scripts or functions. In the first one, do what you have done, calculate the distance matrix among N documents, then store it [N x N matrix], also you need to store transformed data, count_matrix. Then, when you get a new datapoint, in the second function, calculate the cosine similarity of a new datapoint to all other datapoints in the count_matrix, and append the new [1 x N+1] list to the Matrix. Also, update the count_matrix. Simply, instead of doing creating [N+1 x N+1] matrix, store the data and when you have a new data, calculate [1 x N+1] and combine and store it.

Comment: @ShahriyarMammadli Thanks much! your suggesting worked, could you please add it as an answer, so that I can accept it and upvote it. Thanks much!

Comment: I am glad it solved your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of transforming, and calculating the whole cosine similarity matrix every time you receive a new data point, store your existent data, and whenever you get a new sample calculate the cosine similarity of a new sample against the existent data. Then append and store it.

That is, you need a two function:

- First function - Calculate the distance matrix among N existent documents, then store it to the [N x N matrix], also you need to store transformed data, *count_matrix*.
- Second function - When you get a new data point, calculate the cosine similarity of a new datapoint to all existent datapoints in the count_matrix, and append the new [1 x N+1] list to the existent cosine similarity matrix. Also, update the *count_matrix*. Afterward, store both.

Simply, instead of creating [N+1 x N+1] matrix, store the data and when you have new data, calculate [1 x N+1] and combine it with the existent matrix and store it.

Comment: Accepted the answer, but it didn't allow me to upvote as I have fewer points, thanks much!